# Linq to XML: parsing the data but not fetching it

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I'm trying to retrieve XML data that looks like this:

```
<servers>    
<server id="256698330093839" name="Blackstar Games Server" address="blackstar.xs4all.nl"
    port="6774" num_users="13" version="1.2" start="1286488744">        
</server>
... more records snipped ...
</servers>
```

with this code:

```
            WebClient client = new WebClient();
            var url = "http://www.openrpg.com/openrpg_servers.php";
            Program.log(url);
            var s = client.DownloadString(url);
            Program.log(s);
            var xml = XElement.Parse(s);
            var servers =
                from e in xml.Descendants("servers")
                select new Server
                {
                    port = (int)e.Attribute("port"),
                    users = (int)e.Attribute("num_users"),
                    name = (string)e.Attribute("name"),
                    address = (string)e.Attribute("address"),
                };
```

Gets as far as successfully parsing the data into the element tree in `xml`, doesn't throw any exceptions, but when it's done, `servers` is empty instead of containing the list of servers. Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to get the sequence of all elements with the name `server`, not `servers`, so you have to use

```
from e in xml.Descendants("server")
```

Also, I would recommend using `Elements()` instead of `Descendants()` if you want to retrieve only direct children.